# Trying to print on plastic

Tags: print-design

Please excuse my ignorance and potentially wrong forum for this to be posted in.

I am desperately trying to print some numbers on a very simple piece of plastic like shown below (this is not my image). These little plastic ties are tied onto rope for a boat and used to mark the depth of water.

[image]

What type of plastic is the plastic shown above? Is it PVC? Vinyl? (I know it's difficult to say definitely by any guidance is appreciated) Something else? I have absolutely no idea what to even search for. This plastic needs to be durable and printable.

Comment: Most likely you want something like Tyvek and you'll probably need a professional commercial printer - a home inkjet printer isn't going to work. The inks aren't designed to be waterproof or permanent. Of course. that sample is just a Sharpie scribbled on plastic.

Comment: Side note to Scott's comment as he mentions inkjet printers...if you do get your hands on Tyvek, do not attempt to print on it using a laser printer either as you'll probably end up with a melted mess.

Comment: PVC = vinyl. Waterproof for fresh water or seawater? Digital printer ink might not be durable enough. Ask a printer for vinyl outdoor banners. Or print it yourself with stamps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not trying to be an a** but your answer and best option is to call 2-3 print places in your area/country. They will tell you all you need to know and give you the **material**, **price** and **timings** on the spot, perhaps even offering a better material option (if exists) than the one in your pic.

I also advise if possible to **GO PERSONALLY** to a print place, and **FEEL** the material/s they offer. We do the same with paper print, why not with plastic?

P.S

Basically you can print on ANYTHING these days, it's only a matter of price and if the print shop supports it.